# You cannot accept payments using this API as it is no longer supported in India Next js, Strapi , Stripe

Tags: javascript, next.js, stripe-payments, strapi, stripe-payments-js

i am creating a website in "next js" with the backend of "Strapi". This is a simple ecommerce type project. The payment gateway i am using is "Stripe". I included my code for checkout in both frontend and the backend and when i am using test mode in "Stripe" it is working well but when i am putting my real credentials there is showing an error.

```
{"error": {
"message": "You cannot accept payments using this API as it is no longer supported in India. Please refer to https://stripe.com/docs/payments for accepting payments.",
"type": "invalid_request_error"}}
```

I am confused why this is working fine in demo and not in real.

Below is my code:-

1. My strapi backend

```
"use strict";

/**
 *  order controller
 */

const stripe = require("stripe")(
  "sk_test_my_test_code_from_stripe"
);



const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;



module.exports = createCoreController("api::order.order", ({ strapi }) => ({
  async create(ctx) {
    const {
      shippingAdress,
      city,
      state,
      amount,
      pin,
      mobile_number,
      name,
      token,
      items,
    } = ctx.request.body;

    await stripe.charges.create({
      amount: amount * 100,
      currency: "INR",
      source: token,
      description: `order by user ${ctx.state.user.email}`,
    });

    const order = await strapi.db.query("api::order.order").create({
      data: {
        shippingAdress,
        city,
        state,
        amount,
        pin,
        mobile_number,
        name,
        token,
        items,
        user: ctx.state.user.email,
      },
    });
    return order;
  },
}));
```

my next js frontend

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import {BACKEND_URL} from '../helper/baseUrl'
import {
  CardElement,
  Elements,
  useStripe,
  useElements,
} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
// import { strip } from 'jest-docblock';
import { useCart } from 'react-use-cart';
// import {BACKEND_URL} from '../helpers'
const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_code_from_stripe');


const CheckoutForm = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const [formData,setFormData] = useState({})
    const [payProcessing,setPayProcessing] = useState(false)
    const [error,setError] = useState(false)
    const [done,setDone] = useState(false)


    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();
    const {cartTotal,items,emptyCart} = useCart()
    const [paybutton,setPayButton] = useState(true)
    //amount,shippingAddress,city,state,pin,token
    const handleChange = (e)=>{
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            [e.target.name]:e.target.value
        })
    }

    
    const makePaymentRequest = async (allformData)=>{
        try{
            const res = await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/api/orders`,{
                method:"post",
                headers:{
                    "Content-Type":"application/json",
                    "Authorization":"Bearer "+localStorage.getItem("jwt")
                },
                body:JSON.stringify(allformData)
    
            })
            if(res.status != 200) throw Error('Payment failed')
            return await res.json()
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
            setError(true)
        }

    }
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        if (elements == null) {
          return;
        }
       const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement)
       const payload = await stripe.createToken(cardElement)
     
       const allFormData = {
           ...formData,
           token:payload.token.id,
           amount:cartTotal,
           items:items
       }
        setPayProcessing(true)
        await makePaymentRequest(allFormData)
        setDone(true)
        setPayProcessing(false)
        emptyCart()

      };
    if(error) return <div className="text-center"> <h1 className="text-danger mt-5">Payment failed</h1></div>
    if(done) return <div className="text-center"><h1 className="text-success mt-5">Payment done successfully</h1> </div>
    // if(payProcessing) return <h1>Payment is processing...</h1>
    if(payProcessing)  return  <div className="text-center"> <h1 className="text-success mt-5">Wait, Processing Your Payment</h1> </div>
    return (
        <form className='mt-5' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="mb-3">

            <input 
            type="text"
             name="shippingAdress"
             placeholder="Your Address"
             onChange={handleChange}
             className="form-control"
             required
            />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
            <input 
             type="text"
             name="city"
             placeholder="City"
             onChange={handleChange}
             className="form-control"
             required
            />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
            <input 
             type="text"
             name="state"
             placeholder="State"
             onChange={handleChange}
             className="form-control"
             required
            />
            </div>

            <div className="mb-3">

            <input 
             type="number"
             name="pin"
             placeholder="Pin Code"
             onChange={handleChange}
             className="form-control"
             required
             />
             </div>

             <div className="mb-3">
            <input 
             type="number"
             name="mobile_number"
             placeholder="Mobile Number"
             onChange={handleChange}
             className="form-control"
             required
            />
            </div>

            <div className="mb-3">
            <input 
             type="text"
             name="name"
             placeholder="Name"
             onChange={handleChange}
             className="form-control"
             required
            />
            </div>

            <CardElement onChange={(e)=>{
                if(e.complete){
                  setPayButton(false)
                }else{
                    setPayButton(true)
                }
            }} />
            <br />
            <div className="text-center">

            <button className="btn btn-success" style={{width:'40%'}} type="submit" disabled={(!stripe || !elements) || paybutton}>
                Pay Now
            </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}

const Checkout = ()=>{
    return(
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
         <CheckoutForm />
       </Elements>
    )
}



export default Checkout
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.5.5",
    "@auth0/nextjs-auth0": "^1.7.0",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.7.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.22.0",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "graphql": "^16.3.0",
    "next": "12.0.9",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-carousel-slider": "^2.0.13",
    "react-countup": "^6.1.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-image-gallery": "^1.2.7",
    "react-number-easing": "^1.0.2",
    "react-toastify": "^8.1.0",
    "react-use-cart": "^1.13.0",
    "tiny-slider": "^2.9.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.7.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.9"
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this helps you?:
https://support.stripe.com/questions/rbi-regulations-affecting-payments-from-india-issued-cards

I would suggest you describe your issue to the  Stripe support.

Comment: Have you switched from the test key to the live key in your back end code? The code you posted shows your using the test key.

Comment: @Vincenzo Yes I tried to use my live key but still the issue not resolved.

Comment: As per the callout at the top of this [page](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-charges), Indian merchants can no longer use the Charges API due to new RBI regulations. You should refactor your integration to use the Payment Intents API.

Comment: Yeap, you need to use Payment Intents API as suggested by Jonathan Steele.

Answer (score 3):

It might be cause you're using [charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges) API, which does not support 3d secure transactions.

Try to use [payment intents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents) API, it supports 3d secure transactions, it'll work.

However you'll get payment acknowledgment response through [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)

Answer (score 3):

As per latest RBI guidelines, Stripe has switched from Charges API to Payment Intent API. Use below API as per data :

```
Stripe::PaymentIntent.create(
  :customer => customer.id,
  :amount => params[:amount],
  :description => 'Rails Stripe transaction',
  :currency => 'usd',
)
```

It worked for me.
Checkout Stripe API documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create?lang=ruby)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You have given a reasonable reason for the issue/requirement, but have given Ruby code instead of JavaScript.